# Who sells alchemy recipes?

Tags: the-witcher-3

Alchemy can be pretty powerful in the game, and there is a huge difference between the simple versions of potions, oils and bombs and the enhanced or superior versions. The superior versions are often much better than the first ones you can craft.

My main problem is that I'm still missing many recipies, especially annoying is missing the first one and being unable to craft the enhanced and superior versions due to that. I've been trying to buy all recipies I could find, but I'm certain that I haven't found everyone that sells alchemy recipies.

Who are the merchants that sell alchemy recipies, and where can I find them?

Comment: Are you looking for specific vendors? This seems like it's an extremely large answer, potentially.

Comment: Additionally, I've always been vaguely careful, but I'm starting to believe that when you've purchased a recipe, it disappears from vendors. Has anyone seen this occurring? (it will make exact listing of where items are purchasable difficult if you're playing organically)

Comment: @Jeeva Once you purchase a recipe, you learn it automatically. This will prevent you from buying the same recipe over and over and over. I actually quite like this function.

Comment: @Jeeva I don't expect this list to be too long, there don't seem to be all that many merchants around that sell recipies.

Comment: Keyra got lots of recipes.

Comment: You can find a druid with 50+ recipes in the druid camp in skellige

Comment: Complete the quest 'Practicum in Advanced Alchemy'.  That will give you access to the master alchemist who stocks most, if not all, of the recipes.

Answer (score 1):

A few vendors (to be firmed up when I get to my PC):

- The Halfling Herbalist, south Novigrad (mid-high tier)
- Herbalist, Hierarch Square (low tier)

Answer (score 0):

There are many vendors that sell alchemy recipes. Maybe this [alchemy guide](http://www.idigitaltimes.com/witcher-3-alchemy-guides-heres-every-potion-formula-and-ingredient-list-we-found-so-445363) will help.

Comment: Please include relevant content in your answer. Just providing a link means that if it goes offline or changes, we lose the answers value.